# Math/Algorithm for Simple Game Programming (Newbie)?

Tags: algorithm, math

I am a newbie on game programming, i usually programmed enterprise software.

my questions is which math do i need to learn in order for me to create these games

- Snake game
- Tetris
- Card Games like solitaire and the like

Any reference/books that will help me to create this game is very much appreciated

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - I hope you found our answers helpful. Please don't be discouraged by the question having been closed! You should come back to ask more questions about specific problems you encounter as you get into game development :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need much math for those games if you know how to handle some basic data structures like lists and "two-dimensional" arrays.

EDIT:
In addition, that kind of game logic probably comprises a rather small fraction of the code in  your game. The rest is handling user input, graphics, sound, time etc., and doing this properly (having a good architecture in the program) is a more challenging task. On the other hand, at least some of these things can be delegated to a ready-made game engine / framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general guideline, you probably don't have to worry about "which math do i need to learn" unless you're using programming to solve a math problem.

For stuff like programming simple games, it's much more important to learn your data structures and algorithms well, and to be able to design and implement clean, correct, and maintainable code. Math doesn't usually come into the picture unless you're trying to compare two different implementations, and even then, you really only need enough to have an intuitive sense of what constitutes fast enough for what you need.

Comment: I think you can't say "as a general guidline" as it depends on the game itself. While the mentioned games don't need much math, other advanced games may depend heavily on math.

Comment: I guess that's true. My main point was that worrying about data structures/algorithms/implementing the code is usually a bigger problem, and worrying about the math is irrelevant if you don't have the other stuff down.

Answer (score 0):

For programming simple games, the only math you will need is very basic spatial reasoning so that you can tell the compute where to draw/animate objects on the screen. Hence in this case I wouldn't worry about a lack of math background. You may need math as you write more complex games but I recommend just exploring game development freely and brushing up mathematically as required :)

Since you specifically asked about simple games, here are some examples of the kinds of math problems you would have to solve for the games you've described:

- Suppose you're coding up a solitaire game and the cards are `w` pixels wide each, laid out horizontally, separated by `p` pixels each. You would have to deduce that the `n`<sup>th</sup> card is at position (`w` + `p`) * n.
- Let's say you're programming tetris, you might want the blocks glide smoothly to the next grid cell every `m` milliseconds. Well then you'd need to move each block by `[grid cell size] * 1000 / (m * [frames per second])` pixels each frame.

Comment: Thanks @cam i will take note of that stuff